# Intersect detection on a transparent image

Tags: objective-c, collision-detection

[image: EDIT** I have attached an image trying to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. As you can see all the white area is transparent as basically if my car crosses the the bounds of the road you die. Hopefully that makes a little more sense]Here's my issue. I am making a small car game in xcode. I am using around separate 20 .png images as my road. each image is around 600 x 1200 but the road itself is in the centre of the image and it's narrow and winding. I have no idea how I can get the car to detect where it has crossed the edge of the road. I really hope this is making sense to someone.

I don't have any code to share as I am completely stuck on how to do it, and I have been searching everywhere before I came here to ask.

I really appreciate some help.
Thanks

[EDIT** I have attached an image trying to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. As you can see all the white area is transparent as basically if my car crosses the the bounds of the road you die. Hopefully that makes a little more sense

Comment: Sorry bud, but without a little bit more to go on (perhaps an illustration?) you're not going to get much of an answer - CGRectIntersectsRect might do what you want, but by the sounds of it it's more complex than that.

Comment: There are many things to consider. The easiest way is to use existing physic engine.

Comment: Consider using Sprite Kit.

Comment: What does this have to do with "a transparent image"?

Comment: Does this help to understand with the image now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an image for your road, try using a single UIBezierPath, which you can construct from lines and arcs. You can then use containsPoint: to determine if any of the corners of your "car", return NO for that method.

Comment: is there any tutorial that i can learn how to make a road using this method?

Comment: @user2632573, I'm sure there are, but I don't know of any good for your specific purpose. If you learn the basics of using bezier paths, I'm sure you won't find it that difficult to construct what you want.